# How to get column count in ms access database from c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to get a sum with a column from a ms access database but so not nothing has worked this is what I have

```
      Conn.Open();
            Command.CommandText = "Select SUM(c_qty) from COLLVAULT_COINS WHERE c_type!='US Currency' AND c_type!='World Currency' AND c_type!='World Coins' AND c_listName = '" + activeCollection + "'";
            int total_1 = Convert.ToInt32(Command.ExecuteScalar());
            //total sum - get how many match the query
            lblcollectedcount.Text = Convert.ToString(total_1);
            Conn.Close();
```

any help would be nice.

Comment: not equal is `<>` not `!=` https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Table-of-operators-e1bc04d5-8b76-429f-a252-e9223117d6bd

Comment: What is the definition of `not working`? Share some more code and tell us what error you are seeing?

Comment: Message=Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'c_type!='US Currency' AND c_type!='World Currency' AND c_type!='World Coins' AND c_listName = 'test-acc''.
 and it highlights the int total_1 = Convert.ToInt32(Command.ExecuteScalar());

Comment: @Slai got it working. your answer helped. This is first time trying to do this in c# with access so I thought it was !=  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this, assuming you want the number of records that were matched with your query:

```
Conn.Open();
Command.CommandText = "Select SUM(c_qty) as sum, Count(*) as count from COLLVAULT_COINS WHERE c_type <> 'US Currency' AND c_type <> 'World Currency' AND c_type <> 'World Coins' AND c_listName = '" + activeCollection + "'";    //

int total_matches = 0;

using (MySqlDataReader dataReader = Command.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (dataReader.Read()) 
    {
        lblcollectedcount.Text = Convert.ToString(dataReader["sum"]);
        total_matches = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader["count"]);
    } 
    else 
    {
        //nothing was read, handle that case
    }
}

Conn.Close();
```

EDIT:

Misunderstood what the OP was asking for, and I also didn't catch the '<>' error.

I'll still keep this answer here, just for reference code.

Answer (score 1):

```
      Conn.Open();
            Command.CommandText = "Select SUM(c_qty) from COLLVAULT_COINS WHERE c_type <>'US Currency' AND c_type<>'World Currency' AND c_type<>'World Coins' AND c_listName = '" + activeCollection + "'";
            int total_1 = Convert.ToInt32(Command.ExecuteScalar());
            //total records
            lblcollectedcount.Text = Convert.ToString(total_1);
            Conn.Close();
```

I had to use <> as not equals to instead of !=